# Javascript - Div tag auto closing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am changing my website to a modern web app of sorts, here is my HTML code..

```
<joexn-profile>
<joexn-logo></joexn-logo>
<joexn-text></joexn-text>
</joexn-profile>
```

and this is the JavaScript I use for the `<joexn-profile>` tags.

```
var joexnprofile = document.querySelector('joexn-profile');
joexnprofile.insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterBegin', '<center><div class="joexn-profile">');
joexnprofile.insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterEnd', '</div></center>');
```

The issue is, the `<div class="joexn-profile">` tag automatically closes.

Take a look at the inspect element view:

[image]

JavaScript Only

Comment: as far as I can see, you're closing it in the `joexnprfile.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', '</div></center>);`

Comment: @Jorrex — That's what the OP is **trying** to do, the screenshot of the DOM they included shows that that is not what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

As already explained by Quentin, you can't insert only half of a Node.

On the other hand, why do you want to do that at all?

1st: avoid tags like `<center>` or `<font>` or `<b>`, ... If you want to style sth. do it with CSS.

and 2nd: what's the point in replacing `<joexn-profile>` with `<div class="joexn-profile">`? 
Every style that you apply to the `.joexn-profile` CSS-Selector you can also apply to the `joexn-profile` CSS-Selector.

The only difference is, that you have to declare `display:block` for `joexn-profile` so that the browser knows how to render this Node; `block` or `inline` or whatever.

---

But if you insist in going your way, here a little utility to handle such compositions of html-markup (even partial) and DON-Nodes.

**Disclaimer:** Code not fully tested, it may still contain bugs. And `fragment()` doesn't handle cyclic references!

https://jsfiddle.net/mkapLz1k/1/

```
//just to be clear: this ain't a replacement for jQuery, nor does it interfere with it's purposes.
//it's a set of utilities to enable working with compositions of HTML-Markup and plain DOM-Nodes
var nodeUtils = (function(){
    var container = document.createElement("div"), 
        placeholder = document.createElement("div"),
        forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

    function _replacePlaceholder(node){
        var parent = node.parentNode;
        parent.insertBefore(this[node.id], node);
        parent.removeChild(node);
    }

    function _randomId(){
        return ("id"+Math.random()+Math.random()+Math.random()).replace(/0\./g, "-")
    }

    function _fragment(src){
        var markup = [], 
            nodesById = {}, 
            id = "", 
            ids = [];

        function _addNode(node){
            if(!id){
                nodesById[id=_randomId()] = fragment();
                ids.push("#"+id);
                //add placeholder into the html-markup.
                //These placeholder get eventually replaced.
                markup.push('<div id="'+id+'"></div>');
            }
            nodesById[id].appendChild( node );
        }

        function _parse(node){
            if(node == null || node === "" || typeof node === "function") return;

            if(typeof node === "object"){
                if("nodeType" in node){
                    //processes DOM Nodes, of all shapes and sizes ;)
                    //including Comment-Nodes, TextNodes and DocumentFragments, ...
                    _addNode( node );
                }else if(this.NodeList && node instanceof NodeList){
                    //nodeLists change
                    //so I have to process them differently than regular lists
                    while(node.length) _addNode( node[0] );
                }else{
                    //processes anything ArrayLike
                    for(var i = 0, len = ("length" in node && node.length)|0; i<len; ++i)
                        i in node && _parse( node[i] );
                }
            }else{
                //processes primitives as html-markup
                id = "";
                markup.push( node );
            }
        }

        _parse( src );

        if(ids.length === markup.length){ //=> 0 or 1
            //src contained only Nodes, no strings or primitives
            return id? nodesById[id]: void 0;
        }

        //src contained html-markup that needs to be parsed
        container.innerHTML = markup.join("");
        if(ids.length){
            //injecting the DOM-Nodes
            forEach.call( container.querySelectorAll( ids.join(",") ), _replacePlaceholder, nodesById );
        }

        for(var frag = fragment(), fc; fc = container.firstChild; )
            frag.appendChild( fc );
        return frag;
    }


    //`fragment()` is shorthand for `document.createDocumentFragment()`
    //`fragment(composition)` returns a DocumentFragment, that can be used with `node.appendChild()`.

    //takes an arbitrary composition of nested Arrays (or ArrayLike-structures, like jQuery-Objects, NodeLists, ...), containing DOM-Nodes or strings/primitives and builds a DocumentFragment out of that
    function fragment(composition){
        return composition != null && _fragment(composition) || document.createDocumentFragment();
    }


    //all the following functions can take anything that `fragment()` can handle as input:
    //only `node` has to be a real DOM-Node!

    //almost like setting a Nodes innerHTML, but it takes more than just HTML-Markup
    function content(node, composition){
        for(var frag = fragment(composition), fc; fc=node.firstChild;) node.removeChild(fc);
        node.appendChild(frag);
        return node;
    }

    //replace a Node with the provided 
    function replace(node, composition){
        var parent = node.parentNode;

        parent.insertBefore(placeholder, node);
        parent.insertBefore(fragment(composition), placeholder);
        parent.removeChild(placeholder);

        //how parent could have changed? maybe you referenced node somewhere in composition.
        if(parent === node.parentNode) parent.removeChild(node);

        return node;
    }

    //wraps a Node in the provided markup.
    //beforeBegin and afterEnd CAN contain associated markup. Like opening and closing Tag of the same Node.
    //e.g.: wrapNode(node, "<div>", "</div>");
    function wrapNode(node, beforeBegin, afterEnd){
        return replace(node, [beforeBegin, node, afterEnd]);
    }

    //wraps the content of the node in the provided Markup.
    //afterBegin and beforeEnd CAN contain associated markup. Like opening and closing Tag of the same Node.
    function wrapContent(node, afterBegin, beforeEnd){
        node.appendChild(fragment([afterBegin, node.childNodes, beforeEnd]));
        return node;
    }

    return {
        fragment: fragment,
        replace: replace,
        wrapNode: wrapNode,
        wrapContent: wrapContent,
        content: content,
    }   
})();
```

and your Markup:

```
var joexnprofile = document.querySelector('joexn-profile');

//telling by your code, it's not entirely clear 
//wich of these you actually want to do:

nodeUtils.wrapNode(
    joexnprofile,
    '<center><div class="joexn-profile">',
    '</div></center>'   
);

//or
nodeUtils.wrapContent(
    joexnprofile,
    '<center><div class="joexn-profile">',
    '</div></center>'   
);

//or maybe
nodeUtils.replace(
    //replace this:
    joexnprofile, 

    //with this:
    [
        '<center><div class="joexn-profile">',
        joexnprofile.childNodes,
        '</div></center>'
    ]
);
```

Take a look at the code-examples and you get a first impression of what `fragment()` is able to handle

```
var frag = nodeUtils.fragment([ 
    //you can build this Array inline, no need to do that beforehand
    condition? 
        window.title: 
        //simply inject `null` or `undefined` or `""` and this entry will be ignored
        null,

    //nest Arrays, they get parsed recursively
    [
        //mix (partial) HTML with other types
        '<div class="columns">',
            //real Nodes in the middle of some Markup: check
            document.getElementById('leftColumn'),

            //even more nesting, no problem
            [
                '<div class="middle">', 

                //handles anything Arraylike that contains Nodes or Markup
                jQuery('.someClass'),

                "</div>"
            ]
        '</div>'
    ],

    //NodeLists, no Problem
    document.querySelectorAll("#footer > div")
])
```

Now it's up to you how you use this.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the abstraction offered by `insertAdjacentHTML`, you are still working on a DOM. It has elements in a strict hierarchy, it doesn't have start and end tags.

The HTML will be converted to DOM nodes and inserted. You aren't editing the raw source code.

Use `createElement` instead. Get the element you want inside the new element using `querySelector` and then use `appendChild` to move it inside the new element.

Comment: I am quite new to JavaScript, how would I do that?

Comment: `var div = document.createElement("div"); joexnprofile.parentNode.insertBefore(div, joexnprofile); div.appendChild(joexnprofile);`

Comment: The part you included in the question. (Obviously you'd need to add your other elements and attributes too).

Comment: Nope I am completely lost.. here is a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Xj8sgzJ9) would you care to elaborate what you mean specifically? When I say I'm new I mean really new.